# Which framework should I use for mail application for iPad

Tags: ios, imap

I want to prepare the application for iPad to access the mails from the server through IMAP. I have to prepare the local storage for the mails so that all mails get accessed even without internet connection and I also have to perform the other mail services like sending, forwarding, INBOX, deletion, reply, reply all and save as draft functionality for the mails that are coming from the server. So Which framework should I have to use so that all things get possible by that framework or may create less problems by using it.

So, which one is the best framework for me.

Because after using some framework if found that something is not possible from the framework which I have used then it founds to be more problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use MailCore framework for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add  `MessageUIFrameWork` to your project and `include #import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>` and adopt protocol
in your .h  file and implement the delegate methods of `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: Can it be possible to prepare the local storage from this framework.?

Comment: Can you be specific about local storage

Comment: Yes..I am very much specific about local storage of mails.

Comment: into your app or your ipad. if you configured your email it will in your ipad local storage .

Comment: yes...It is in my iPad at some path. Do you have some sample code or can you please tell me the methods which are to be used during this procedure for creation of local storage in iPad.

Comment: please follow this [here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/18176-iPhone-MFMailcomposeviewcontroller-example.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14723/discussion-between-vinodh-and-vikas-ahuja)